# Subprocess call does not accept variables

Tags: python, subprocess

I try something like this in Python:

```
import os, subprocess

varA = 'argument1=a'
varB = 'argument2=b'

subprocess.call([command, varA, varB])
```

which does not work. It seems like that not all arguments are reaching the command.

If I do:

```
subprocess.call([command, 'arugment1=a', 'argument2=b'])
```

It works.

Comment: There must be something else going on here, because this doesn't make sense. The two versions of `subprocess.call()` in your question are completely equivalent, except for the typo in `arugment1=a` in the second example. `subprocess.call()` doesn't know how the array values got there - whether they were string literals or variables. It just sees the end result. Try using `print()` on those arrays instead of `subprocess.call()` and see what it prints out.

Comment: I´m doing that, (did that) via logging.info() Well, the program called is something like virtual env (called vshell, vrun) which creates a virtual env and then calls jython. I think it might have something to do with that. .. But on the other side. It does not make any sense...

Comment: If using `print()` (oops, I see you're using `logging.info()`) doesn't make the problem apparent, I suggest putting the code online using [Try It Online](https://tio.run/) or a similar service. You probably won't be able to use `subprocess.call()` but you can use `print()` or `logging.info()` instead. (It's almost certain that the problem has nothing to do with `subprocess.call()`.)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8RpmapYC you can take a look :) 

The old version had params = params + 'argument'

Which neither did´nt work. I basically copy and pasted the code from above into call()

Comment: That pastebin is pretty complicated and different from the code in your question. Can we try for simple, self-contained test cases? For example, paste this into your Python console: `print([ 'a', 'b' ]); a = 'a'; b = 'b'; print([ a, b ])` - it will print the same thing twice. If you work with simple examples like this, they should help reveal whatever you're doing wrong.

Comment: I tried already a simplified version with static arguments in a separate file (test.py) where I get the same behaviour.

I thought it has something to do how python calls work. (I´m pretty new to python.)

The other idea is, as I wrote above, it basically calls a shell script, which calls a wrapper, which calls a jython.  Which might be the caveat how python calls work?

Comment: @Unomagan Probably `var1` and `var2` just contain something different that what you posted in your question. Maybe it has to do with string formatting or where you get those values from could play a role too. As already mentioned, the pastebin code is very different from the one in your question and thus is is not at all clear what the problem is. Because the code in your question will just run fine.

Comment: One thing to understand about Python (and many similar languages) is that when you call a function and pass it either a string literal or a variable containing a string, the function doesn't have any way of knowing which way you did it. Inside the function they are exactly the same. There will never be any difference between doing `foo('a')` vs. `x = 'a'; foo(x)` - the `foo` function sees the same thing either way.